# My code draw image in the wrong place in the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need your help , I am facing a problem with my code , here I am trying to draw a dount chart with lines out from each sector and in the end of line I am drawing icons , but unfortunately the images are not drawn in the correct place , so this is my code and I need your help.

```
<body>

    <canvas id="chart" width=1000 height=900 style="background-color:#6d6363">  </canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var canvas  = document.getElementById("chart");
        var chart = canvas.getContext("2d");
        function drawdountChart(canvas)
        {

            this.x , this.y , this.radius , this.lineWidth , this.strockStyle , this.from , this.to = null;
            this.set = function( x, y, radius, from, to, lineWidth, strockStyle)
            {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
                this.radius = radius;
                this.from=from;
                this.to= to;
                this.lineWidth = lineWidth;
                this.strockStyle = strockStyle; 
            }

            this.drawImg = function(x , y , imagePath) // this is the function where I draw my image 
            {

                var image = document.createElement("img");
                image.src=imagePath;
                image.onload=(function()
                { 
                    canvas.drawImage(image , x , y);

                });

            }

            this.draw = function(data)
            {
                canvas.beginPath();
                canvas.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
                canvas.strokeStyle = this.strockStyle;
                canvas.arc(this.x , this.y , this.radius , this.from , this.to);
                canvas.stroke();
                var numberOfParts = data.numberOfParts;
                var parts = data.parts;
                var colors = data.colors;
                var icons = data.icons;
                var artPercentage = null;
                var beginFrom = 0;
                var currentX = null;
                var currentY = null;
               for(var i = 0; i<numberOfParts; i++)
               {
                    percentage= parts[i]/this.radius;
                    canvas.beginPath();
                    canvas.lineWidth=30;
                    canvas.strokeStyle = colors[i];
                    canvas.arc(this.x , this.y ,this.radius , beginFrom , (Math.PI*2*percentage)+beginFrom , false);
                    var x_axis = (this.radius*Math.cos(beginFrom))+this.x;
                    var y_axis = (this.radius*Math.sin(beginFrom))+this.y;
                    var angleInDegree = beginFrom*57.3;
                    beginFrom = (Math.PI*2*percentage)+beginFrom;
                    canvas.stroke();
                    canvas.beginPath();
                    canvas.lineWidth = 1;

                   if(angleInDegree>=270&&angleInDegree<360)
                   {
                        canvas.moveTo(x_axis , y_axis);
                        canvas.lineTo(x_axis+150 , y_axis-90);
                        canvas.stroke();
                        canvas.beginPath();
                        canvas.moveTo(x_axis+150 , y_axis-90);
                        canvas.lineTo(x_axis+190 , y_axis-90);
                        canvas.stroke();
                        this.drawImg(x_axis+190 , y_axis-90 , icons[i] ); //calling for my drawImg function where I send the points where the line ends as a parameters and the path of the image to be drawn 
                   }else
                       if(angleInDegree>=0&&angleInDegree<90)
                       {
                            canvas.moveTo(x_axis , y_axis);
                            canvas.lineTo(x_axis+150 , y_axis+90);
                            canvas.stroke();
                            canvas.beginPath();
                            canvas.moveTo(x_axis+150 , y_axis+90);
                            canvas.lineTo(x_axis+190 , y_axis+90);
                            canvas.stroke();

                            this.drawImg(x_axis+190 , y_axis-90 , icons[i] );//calling for my drawImg function where I send the points where the line ends as a parameters and the path of the image to be drawn 



                       }else                               
                           if(angleInDegree>=90&&angleInDegree<180)
                           {
                               canvas.moveTo(x_axis , y_axis);
                               canvas.lineTo(x_axis-150 , y_axis+90);
                               canvas.stroke();
                               canvas.beginPath();
                               canvas.moveTo(x_axis-150 , y_axis+90);
                               canvas.lineTo(x_axis-190 , y_axis+90);
                               canvas.stroke();
                               this.drawImg(x_axis-190 , y_axis-90 , icons[i] );//calling for my drawImg function where I send the points where the line ends as a parameters and the path of the image to be drawn 



                           }else
                               if(angleInDegree>=180&&angleInDegree<270)
                               {
                                    canvas.moveTo(x_axis , y_axis);
                                    canvas.lineTo(x_axis-150 , y_axis-90);
                                    canvas.stroke();
                                    canvas.beginPath();
                                    canvas.moveTo(x_axis-150 , y_axis-90);
                                    canvas.lineTo(x_axis-190 , y_axis-90);
                                    canvas.stroke();
                                    this.drawImg(x_axis-190 , y_axis-90 , icons[i] );//calling for my drawImg function where I send the points where the line ends as a parameters and the path of the image to be drawn 
                               }
               }
            }
        }

        var data = 
            {
                numberOfParts: 5,
                parts:[20, 20,65, 25 , 10],
                colors:["red", "green", "blue", "yellow" , "orange" ], 
                comments:["comment1", "comment2", "comment3", "comment4" ],
                icons:["images/fb.png", "images/fB.png", "images/fb.png", "images/fb.png", "images/fb.png"]
            };
        var drawDount = new drawdountChart(chart);
        drawDount.set(400, 400, 140, 0, Math.PI*2, 30, "#FFF");
        drawDount.draw(data);

    </script>
</body>
```

[image]

this was the result ,  but that is not what I want  , I need every icon to  be drawn in the end of its line

Comment: Could you save the canvas generated and upload it ? Then add the image in your question, it will help a lot.

Comment: @agrum I added it to the question

Comment: Thank you, with the image I nailed it down I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in `this.drawImg(x_axis  +X , y_axis + Y , icons[i] );`

The one in the first `if` if alright, the three others aren't.

1. `this.drawImg(x_axis+190 , y_axis-90 , icons[i] );`
2. `this.drawImg(x_axis+190 , y_axis+90 , icons[i] );`
3. `this.drawImg(x_axis-190 , y_axis+90 , icons[i] );`
4. `this.drawImg(x_axis-190 , y_axis-90 , icons[i] );`

Do not forget to also add the shift corresponding to the size of your image.

1. Shift vertically by `-heightIcon / 2`
2. For icons on the left of the chart, shift horizontally by `-widthIcon`

Comment: oh , thank you so much , I did not notice that I did not change all values when I copied and pasted the same line multiple times. @agrum

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you need ?
just corrected few things on your script... few unnecessary blank spaces...

http://jsfiddle.net/vitorboccio/p4LxZ/

```
var canvas  = document.getElementById("chart");
var chart = canvas.getContext("2d");
function drawdountChart(canvas)
{

    this.x, this.y, this.radius, this.lineWidth, this.strockStyle, this.from, this.to = null;
    this.set = function( x, y, radius, from, to, lineWidth, strockStyle)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.from=from;
        this.to= to;
        this.lineWidth = lineWidth;
        this.strockStyle = strockStyle; 
    };

    this.drawImg = function(x , y , imagePath) // this is the function where I draw my image 
    {

        var image = document.createElement("img");
        image.src=imagePath;
        image.onload=(function()
        { 
            canvas.drawImage(image , x , y);

        });

    };

    this.draw = function(data)
    {
        canvas.beginPath();
        canvas.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
        canvas.strokeStyle = this.strockStyle;
        canvas.arc(this.x , this.y , this.radius , this.from , this.to);
        canvas.stroke();
        var numberOfParts = data.numberOfParts;
        var parts = data.parts;
        var colors = data.colors;
        var icons = data.icons;
        var artPercentage = null;
        var beginFrom = 0;
        var currentX = null;
        var currentY = null;
       for(var i = 0; i<numberOfParts; i++)
       {
            percentage= parts[i]/this.radius;
            canvas.beginPath();
            canvas.lineWidth=30;
            canvas.strokeStyle = colors[i];
            canvas.arc(this.x , this.y ,this.radius , beginFrom , (Math.PI*2*percentage)+beginFrom , false);
            var x_axis = (this.radius*Math.cos(beginFrom))+this.x;
            var y_axis = (this.radius*Math.sin(beginFrom))+this.y;
            var angleInDegree = beginFrom*57.3;
            beginFrom = (Math.PI*2*percentage)+beginFrom;
            canvas.stroke();
            canvas.beginPath();
            canvas.lineWidth = 1;

           if(angleInDegree>=270&&angleInDegree<360)
           {
                canvas.moveTo(x_axis , y_axis);
                canvas.lineTo(x_axis+150 , y_axis-90);
                canvas.stroke();
                canvas.beginPath();
                canvas.moveTo(x_axis+150 , y_axis-90);
                canvas.lineTo(x_axis+190 , y_axis-90);
                canvas.stroke();
                this.drawImg(x_axis+190 , y_axis-90 , icons[i] ); //calling for my drawImg function where I send the points where the line ends as a parameters and the path of the image to be drawn 
           }else
               if(angleInDegree>=0&&angleInDegree<90)
               {
                    canvas.moveTo(x_axis , y_axis);
                    canvas.lineTo(x_axis+150 , y_axis+90);
                    canvas.stroke();
                    canvas.beginPath();
                    canvas.moveTo(x_axis+150 , y_axis+90);
                    canvas.lineTo(x_axis+190 , y_axis+90);
                    canvas.stroke();

                    this.drawImg(x_axis+190 , y_axis-90 , icons[i] );//calling for my drawImg function where I send the points where the line ends as a parameters and the path of the image to be drawn 



               }else                               
                   if(angleInDegree>=90&&angleInDegree<180)
                   {
                       canvas.moveTo(x_axis , y_axis);
                       canvas.lineTo(x_axis-150 , y_axis+90);
                       canvas.stroke();
                       canvas.beginPath();
                       canvas.moveTo(x_axis-150 , y_axis+90);
                       canvas.lineTo(x_axis-190 , y_axis+90);
                       canvas.stroke();
                       this.drawImg(x_axis-190 , y_axis-90 , icons[i] );//calling for my drawImg function where I send the points where the line ends as a parameters and the path of the image to be drawn 



                   }else
                       if(angleInDegree>=180&&angleInDegree<270)
                       {
                            canvas.moveTo(x_axis , y_axis);
                            canvas.lineTo(x_axis-150 , y_axis-90);
                            canvas.stroke();
                            canvas.beginPath();
                            canvas.moveTo(x_axis-150 , y_axis-90);
                            canvas.lineTo(x_axis-190 , y_axis-90);
                            canvas.stroke();
                            this.drawImg(x_axis-190 , y_axis-90 , icons[i] );//calling for my drawImg function where I send the points where the line ends as a parameters and the path of the image to be drawn 
                       }
       }
    };
}

var data = 
    {
        numberOfParts: 5,
        parts:[20, 20,65, 25 , 10],
        colors:["red", "green", "blue", "yellow" , "orange" ], 
        comments:["comment1", "comment2", "comment3", "comment4" ],
        icons:["images/fb.png", "images/fB.png", "images/fb.png", "images/fb.png", "images/fb.png"]
    };
var drawDount = new drawdountChart(chart);
drawDount.set(400, 400, 140, 0, Math.PI*2, 30, "#FFF");
drawDount.draw(data);
```